# Pytesseract issue - No module named 'pytesseract'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, tesseract

I am on a Mac, using Visual Studio Code. I have installed tesseract using "pip3 install tesseract". In terminal, if I run "tesseract" it looks like it is installed.

However, when I run "import pytesseract as tes" in Visual Studio, I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytesseract'" Has anyone had this issue and resolved it?

Comment: VSC may use its own Python installation.

Comment: Did you install tesseract or pytesseract? What I see is that `pip install tesseract` is a [completely different package](https://pypi.org/project/tesseract/) than the OCR engine/package.

Answer (score 1):

> I have installed tesseract using "pip3 install tesseract".
>
> No module named 'pytesseract'

The package you installed and used is not the same.

[The package pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) you want needs to be installed by command `pip3 install pytesseract`.

By the way, if you haven't installed the package, the wavy line provided by Pylance will also remind you that you haven't installed it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would check if the library is in the correct folder with the other packages where VSC go and search for them.

I would try with a more common library with commands like 'import math' and 'import numpy as np' and verify that they are OK. Then verify that tesseract is in the same folder.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you check pypi.org for the package names you’ve mentioned; it looks like these are 2 different packages.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).